# A superfluous but cool dynamic python structure and questions about decorators, comprehensions, syntax

Tags: python, operator-overloading, decorator, list-comprehension

This is just a fun question about some thing you can do with python syntax.

When I moved from matlab to python, I made a class that worked similarly to matlab's struct

```
class DynStruct(AbstractPrintable):
    ' dynamical add and remove members '
    def __init__(self, child_exclude_list=[]):
        super(DynStruct, self).__init__(child_exclude_list)
```

it is just an object where you can dynamically add members without having to 
resort a dictionary (because I hate typing quotes)

I also made a cool helper class that printed out the members of the class nicely so you can 
see what you're doing while working in IPython. (I'm leaving out my imports, but its just some standard stuff as well as some numpy)

```
class AbstractPrintable(object):
    'A base class that prints its attributes instead of the memory address'
    def __init__(self, child_print_exclude=[]):
        self._printable_exclude = ['_printable_exclude'] + child_print_exclude
    def __str__(self):
        head = printableType(self)
        body = self.printable_attributes()
        body = re.sub('\n *\n *\n','\n\n',body)
        return head+('\n'+body).replace('\n','\n    ')

    def printable_attributes(self, type_bit=True):
        body = ''
        attri_list = []

        for key in self.__dict__.iterkeys():
            if key in self._printable_exclude: continue
            val = self.__dict__[key]
            namestr = str(key)
            valstr  = printableVal(val)
            typestr = printableType(val)
            max_valstr = 10000
            if len(valstr) > max_valstr:
                valstr = valstr[0:max_valstr/2]+valstr[-max_valstr/2:-1]
            attri_list.append( (typestr, namestr, valstr) )

        attri_list.sort()
        for (typestr, namestr, valstr) in attri_list:
            entrytail = '\n' if valstr.count('\n') <= 1 else '\n\n'
            typestr2 = typestr+' ' if type_bit else ''
            body += typestr2 + namestr + ' = ' + valstr + entrytail
        return body
#---------------
def printableType(val):
    if type(val) == numpy.ndarray:
        info = npArrInfo(val)
        _typestr = info.dtypestr
    elif isinstance(val, object):
        _typestr = val.__class__.__name__
    else:
        _typestr = str(type(val))
        _typestr = _typestr.replace('type','')
        _typestr = re.sub('[\'><]','',_typestr)
        _typestr = re.sub('  *',' ',_typestr)
        _typestr = _typestr.strip()
    return _typestr
```

I then had a case where I needed to get a bunch of elements from my DynStruct, so I added a function which returns a tuple of the elements I wanted.

```
# I added this function to DynStruct
def getprops(self, *prop_list):
    return tuple([self.__dict__[prop_name] for prop_name in prop_list])
```

EG:

```
>> point = DynStruct()
>> point.x = 3
>> point.y = 1
>> point.z = 60
>> print point

DynStruct
    int x = 3
    int y = 1
    int z = 60

 >> # Now I want to get the points
 >> (x,y,z) = point.getprops('x','y','z')
```

Now, this works great, and it makes debugging really easy. But I came on a case where I wanted to set a bunch of properties at once (sort of like above). And I realize there are other ways to do this, but I'd really like to have a setprop where the syntax works like this:

```
point.setprops('x','y','z') = (14, 22, 30)
```

I'm not sure, but I feel like there might be a way to do this because of the @someobj.setter decorator. But I don't know how to overload the equals operator to use it in this way, or if its even possible.

I guess in the meantime I'll just write it like this
point.setprops('x','y','z', 14, 22, 30)

Comment: Is the `setprops` **method** a necessity, or would you be willing to have `point.setprops['x', 'y', 'z'] = (14, 22, 30)` (or even `point['x', 'y', 'z'] = (14, 22, 30)`) instead?

Comment: Yes, both of those sound nice. Can you get a dict to work with that syntax, I just tried it and got a key error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right off the bat, you don't *need* this - since you can do:

```
point.x, point.y, point.z = (14, 22, 30)
# Tuple unpacking ... is there nothing it cannot do?
```

However, let's say that this is not clear enough and you really need to be able to set multiple fields at once.  Then you can use [`__setitem__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__):

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    if isinstance(key, tuple):
        for k, v in zip(key, value):
            setattr(self, k, v)
    else:
        setattr(self, key, value)
```

Then you could do as follows:

```
point['x', 'y', 'z'] = (14, 22, 30)
```

Then you could also replace your `getprops` method with the [`__getitem__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) method, similarly implemented and be able to do:

```
x, y, z = point['x', 'y', 'z']
```

Comment: Well, this was a toy example, but I didn't know about set item. That's the sort of thing I was looking for when I posted this.

Answer (score 0):

> it is just an object where you can dynamically add members without having to resort a dictionary (because I hate typing quotes)

Maybe I missed something in your explanation, but can't you already do this?  For example

```
class Foo(Object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

f = Foo()
f.x = 1
f.y = 2
f.z = 3

print f.x, f.y, f.z # outputs 1 2 3
```

As for the second part of your question, about getting this syntax,

`point.setprops('x','y','z') = (14, 22, 30)`

Unfortunately I'm not sure if this is possible.  The reason is that

`point.setprops('x', 'y', 'z')`

is a 'call' expression.  Due to the way python is parsed, I don't think you can have a call expression on the left hand side of an assignment statement.  From what I know, you can only have a list of variable names or slice/index expressions.  That being said, I'm not 100% sure.  There might be some crazy python ninja stuff you can do to make that work.

Comment: You aren't missing anything, you can do this with any object. The printing and getting are the novel features in what I wrote. I just don't know about the setting. I have a hunch it can be done because I know there are decorators which do something like assigning to a call statement. I was wondering if anyone knew the magic words.

Comment: It's not possible to assign to an object. That's a concept that simply doesn't exist in Python. You can only assign to an identifier, an attribute reference, a subscripting or a slice, or any combination of those within one or more (possible nested) tuples or lists. See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) for more details.